# JS (canvas) как дополнительно поменять цвет у вершин

Tags: javascript, php, json, canvas

В JS совсем не силен, требуется помощь сейчас раскраска вершин производится красным цветом, после манипуляций с алгоритмом требуется перекрасить вершины лежащие в файле json,т.е. все вершины должны быть красные, а вершины из файла под именами

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"name1"},{"name":" name0"},{"name":"name3"}]}
```

должны быть любого другого цвета. При построении графа, файл будет постоянно обновляться

```
    (function($){
            var Renderer = function(canvas)
            {
                var canvas = $(canvas).get(0);
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                var particleSystem;
                var particleSystem1;
                var that = {
                    init:function(system){
                        //начальная инициализация
                        particleSystem = system;
                        particleSystem.screenSize(canvas.width, canvas.height);
                        particleSystem.screenPadding(80);
                        that.initMouseHandling();
                    },

                    redraw:function(){
                        //действия при перересовке
                        ctx.fillStyle = "white"; //белым цветом
                        ctx.fillRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //закрашиваем всю область

                        particleSystem.eachEdge( //отрисуем каждую грань
                            function(edge, pt1, pt2){ //будем работать с гранями и точками её начала и конца
                                ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.35)"; //грани будут чёрным цветом с некой прозрачностью
                                ctx.lineWidth = 2; //толщиной в один пиксель
                                ctx.beginPath();  //начинаем рисовать
                                ctx.moveTo(pt1.x, pt1.y); //от точки один
                                ctx.lineTo(pt2.x, pt2.y); //до точки два
                                ctx.stroke();
                            });

                        particleSystem.eachNode( //теперь каждую вершину
                            function(node, pt){  //получаем вершину и точку где она
                                var w = 12;   //ширина квадрата
                                ctx.fillStyle = "red"; // выбираем цвет грани
                                ctx.fillRect(pt.x-w/2, pt.y-w/2, w,w); //рисуем
                                ctx.fillStyle = "black"; //цвет для шрифта
                                ctx.font = 'italic 13px sans-serif'; //шрифт
                                ctx.fillText (node.name, pt.x+10, pt.y+10); //пишем имя у каждой точки
                            });
                    },

                    initMouseHandling:function(){ //события с мышью
                        var dragged = null;   //вершина которую перемещают
                        var handler = {
                            clicked:function(e){ //нажали
                                var pos = $(canvas).offset(); //получаем позицию canvas
                                _mouseP = arbor.Point(e.pageX-pos.left, e.pageY-pos.top); //и позицию нажатия кнопки относительно canvas
                                dragged = particleSystem.nearest(_mouseP); //определяем ближайшую вершину к нажатию
                                if (dragged && dragged.node !== null){
                                    dragged.node.fixed = true; //фиксируем её
                                }
                                $(canvas).bind('mousemove', handler.dragged); //слушаем события перемещения мыши
                                $(window).bind('mouseup', handler.dropped);  //и отпускания кнопки
                                return false;
                            },
                            dragged:function(e){ //перетаскиваем вершину
                                var pos = $(canvas).offset();
                                var s = arbor.Point(e.pageX-pos.left, e.pageY-pos.top);

                                if (dragged && dragged.node !== null){
                                    var p = particleSystem.fromScreen(s);
                                    dragged.node.p = p; //тянем вершину за нажатой мышью
                                }

                                return false;
                            },
                            dropped:function(e){ //отпустили
                                if (dragged===null || dragged.node===undefined) return; //если не перемещали, то уходим
                                if (dragged.node !== null) dragged.node.fixed = false; //если перемещали - отпускаем
                                dragged = null; //очищаем
                                $(canvas).unbind('mousemove', handler.dragged); //перестаём слушать события
                                $(window).unbind('mouseup', handler.dropped);
                                _mouseP = null;
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                        // слушаем события нажатия мыши
                        $(canvas).mousedown(handler.clicked);
                    },
                }
                return that;
            }

            $(document).ready(function(){
                sys = arbor.ParticleSystem(1000); // создаём систему
                sys.parameters({gravity:true}); // гравитация вкл
                sys.renderer = Renderer("#viewport") //начинаем рисовать в выбраной области

                $.getJSON("1.json", //получаем с сервера файл с данными
                    function(data){
                        $.each(data.nodes, function(i,name){
                            sys.addNode(name.name); //добавляем вершину
                        });
                    });
                $.getJSON("2.json", //получаем с сервера файл с данными
                    function(data_1){
                        $.each(data_1.edges, function(i,edge){
                            sys.addEdge(sys.getNode(edge.src),sys.getNode(edge.dest)); //добавляем грань
                        });
                    });
            })

        })(this.jQuery)
```

Помогите пожалуйста переделать скрипт, я не силен в JS

Comment: Вы тут `sys.addNode(name.name);` передаете только св-во объекта, которое выводите потом в строке `ctx.fillText (node.name, pt.x+10, pt.y+10);`. Попробуйте вместо `node.node` передавать просто `node`, а потом считывать, где нужно, цвет, например `node.color`

Comment: @DaemonHK  данный скрипт работает без проблем, там где идет работа с файлом 1 и 2 все хорошо. Потом появляется файл 3 и вот именно тут нужно раскрасить вершины в другой цвет

Comment: Вам нужно передавать цвета, да и вообще любые данные, я примерно описал принцип работы. Как оно работает по умолчанию, дело другое уже